# How to retrieve EJB via JNDI in Tapestry application in OSGi environment running on Glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, osgi, jndi

I'm having problems retrieving my EJB in my Tapestry application.
The other part of application is in OSGi bundle, and all of it is deployed on Glassfish.

Currently, this is how my stuff looks like:

My interface (packaged as jar):

```
@Remote
public interface MyEJBInterface {
    public static final String JNDI_NAME = "ejb/MyEJBInterface";
    public String sayHello(String name);

}
```

My implementation (packaged as bundle):

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = MyEJBInterface.JNDI_NAME, beanInterface = MyEJBInterface.class)
public class MyEJBImplementation implements MyEJBInterface {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

My Tapestry build method in AppModule class:

```
public MyEJBService buildMyEJBService() {
    MyEJBInterface myEjb = new JndiLookupHelper<MyEJBInterface>().lookupNoPrefix(MyEJBInterface.JNDI_NAME);

    MyEJBService service = new MyEJBServiceMock(myEjb);

    return service;
}
```

And I look it up like this:

```
public class JndiLookupHelper<T> {
    private T remoteObject;

    public T lookupNoEjbPrefix(String name) {
        String jndiPath = "java:comp/env/" + name;
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            remoteObject = (T) ic.lookup(jndiPath);
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
        return remoteObject;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the EJB is not found and an exception is thrown:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJBInterface' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/ejb/MyEJBInterface]
```

Comment: And your exception / problem is...?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the exception. It's there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally reached the solution. Here it is:

The interface:

```
public interface MyEJBInterface {
    public static final String JNDI_NAME = "java:global/ejb/MyEJBInterface";
    public String sayHello(String name);

}
```

The implementation:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = MyEJBInterface.JNDI_NAME, beanInterface = MyEJBInterface.class)
public class MyEJBImplementation implements MyEJBInterface {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

The build method:

```
public MyEJBService buildMyEJBService() {
    MyEJBInterface myEjb = new JndiLookupHelper<MyEJBInterface>().lookup(MyEJBInterface.JNDI_NAME);

    MyEJBService service = new MyEJBServiceMock(myEjb);

    return service;
}
```

The lookup:

```
public class JndiLookupHelper<T> {

    private T remoteObject;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T lookup(String name) {
        try {
            remoteObject = (T) InitialContext.doLookup(name);
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
        return remoteObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this is better:

```
public static class EjbServiceBuilder<T> implements ServiceBuilder<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    private String name;

    public EjbServiceBuilder<T>(Class<T> type, String name) {
        this.type= type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public T buildService(ServiceResources resources) {
        try {
            return type.cast(InitialContext.doLookup(name));
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(MyEJBInterface.class, new EjbServiceBuilder<MyEJBInterface>(MyEJBInterface.class, MyEJBInterface.JNDI_NAME));
    binder.bind(MyEJBOtherInterface.class, new EjbServiceBuilder<MyEJBOtherInterface>(...));

    // MyEJBInterface will be injected into MyEJBServiceMock constructor
    binder.bind(MyEJBService.class, MyEJBServiceMock.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare `Export-EJB: ALL` in your manifest.mf

I'm not sure that the EJB's will be available at "java:comp/env/". You might need to lookup via the [portable global JNDI name](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_)

Comment: I have `Export-EJB: ALL`, and I don't have anything under `java:global`, not even a single bean.